# JMeter Couldnt Connect to Phoenix using JDBC Connection

Tags: java, apache, jdbc, jmeter, apache-phoenix

I'm setting up a JMeter Connection to Phoenix using its JDBC Connection Configuration but it wont connect due to some jars and connection problem. I have tried configuring all of the compatible jars and configure the connection but it won't work either.

I've added Phoenix Jar to Classpath in Test Plan Setting.

The JDBC connection setting are as below:

Database Url: `jdbc:phoenix://ip:port:/hbase-unsecure/schema_name`

Driver Class: `org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver`

After configuring the phoenix database all i want to do is to do some simple query like `SELECT * FROM table_name`

Using MySQL Connection was successful and it shows me the data inside the database. However using this Phoenix Configuration, it won't even connect to the database and I am getting various error such as

> Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver' for connect URL

or

> Couldn't established connection

or

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoungError: Could not initialize class org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved. turns out the driver for phoenix (phoenix-4.7.0.2.6.1.0-129-client) is suitable for JMeter version 2.9.
And in order the phoenix driver to work in JMeter, use phoenix-4.7.0.2.6.4.0-91-client, not phoenix-4.7.0.2.6.1.0-129-client.
and if you have service mapping enabled problem, extract your jar, find hbase-default file, and add another property for service mapping enabled = true.